# How to make a Bootstrap Navbar centered and has a specific width which is not responsive or static width?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, width, navbar

I am at the very beginning of my webpage school project.
Finally have a Navbar that looks okay.
Although, I dont want the full length like how it is. 
How can I resize it to be centered and only a specific width?

Thank you!

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Find My Band</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">


  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Find Your Band</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="">Find Band</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Our Team</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What width do you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply set a `width` css style on your navbar using the `.navbar` selector. To center it then you can just use `margin: auto`:

```css
.navbar {
  width: 70%;    /* Set here your width */
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Find My Band</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">


  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

          <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Find Your Band</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="">Find Band</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Our Team</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @DenisKutlovci Not a problem. Can you please `upvote` and `validate` my answer ? Thanks ;)